# Looking for distributed, in-memory Graph DB

Tags: .net, database, in-memory, graph-databases, distributed-database

Is there a database which will satisfy all (or at least most) of this requirements?

1. Graph oriented - optimized for storing graphs and traversal(e.g HyperGraphDB, Neo4j)
2. Running in memory, but having a persisted storage (e.g. Redis)
3. Distributed (e.g. membase)
4. Had .NET adapter (TCP/IP, not HTTP REST)

Or am I asking too much?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post any info about your choice and anything you tried, as this questions was asked about a year before? Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I didn't find any that suits all of them. I've tried many until project requirements changed really big and this branch of development was abandoned.
Have a look here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

I'd recommend to try Objectivity/DB & Versant, we have some specific queries & DB schema that didn't worked with them, but in overal they're pretty good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems hard to find .NET based one... 
I hope this might be helpful:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database

Comment: Sorry for delay, missed this answer somehow. Although it doesn't actually answers my question I believe link provided by Eonil is definitely worth visiting for everyone searching something similar.

Answer (score 0):

JStore is a component of Jalios JCMS with given features:

- Java Graph Database (with CMS advanced concept)
- Running in memory with persisted storage and versioning
- Distributed (replicate between nodes and import/export)

JCMS is a proprietary CMS/GED, Portal, SocialNetwork, Collaboration WebApplication but it is also a powerfull framework around JStore.